# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () . Swagger Configuration not working

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, swagger

> Swagger Configuration not working
> I use swagger with springboot , i am getting error404 when i hit this
> url http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html. I am new to swagger I have
> no idea how to solve it. I create separate configuration file
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> Here all the documentation details

> UserCongig.kt

package com.main.swaggerdemo.config

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2


@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class UserConfig {
    @Bean
    fun postApi(): Docket {
        return Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/*"))
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.main.swaggerdemo"))
            .build()

    }

}
```

> UserController.kt

```
package com.main.swaggerdemo.controller

import com.main.swaggerdemo.entity.User
import com.main.swaggerdemo.model.req.ReqUser
import com.main.swaggerdemo.model.response.RespUser
import com.main.swaggerdemo.repo.UserRepo
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepo: UserRepo

    @GetMapping("/signup")
    @ApiOperation(value = "create new user")
    fun signupUser(@ModelAttribute request: ReqUser): ResponseEntity<*> {
        val newUser = User(name = request.name, country = request.country,
            email = request.email, password = request.password)
        userRepo.save(newUser)
        val resUser = RespUser(newUser.id, newUser.name, newUser.country, newUser.email)
        return ResponseEntity(resUser, HttpStatus.OK)
    }

    @GetMapping("/findByEmail/{email}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "find the user")
    fun getUserByEmail(@PathVariable("email") email: String): ResponseEntity<*> {
        val curentUser = userRepo.findByEmail(email)
        if (curentUser != null) {
            val userData = userRepo.findByEmail(email)
            return ResponseEntity(userData, HttpStatus.OK)
        }
        return ResponseEntity("No data found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    }
}
```

> build-gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.32"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.32"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.4.32"
}

group = "com.main"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: try http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

Answer (score 1):

I have added following changes for my service with swagger. You can try the same.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class UserConfig {

@Bean
public Docket apiDocumentationV1() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/v1/**"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(createMetaData())
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
}

private ApiInfo createMetaData() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Test Service APIs")
            .description("API to maintain test service.")
            .version("1.0.0")
            .build();
}
}
```